# How to read the contents of a packed file when the uses cancels an NSIS installation?

Tags: nsis

I want to report to a Web Service whether the installation completed successfully or not. The identifiers that need to be passed to the service are stored in an uncompressed text file along with the other (compressed) files. Everything works on a successful installation, but when the user cancels the installation, no files are extracted (as expected) and I am unable to find a way to extract a specific file from the archive.

I have considered some other options (writing a custom plugin, parsing through the installer executable file), but I hope there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract files at any point in the installer, in your case probably in `.onInstFailed` or  `.onUserAbort`:

```
Function .onInstFailed
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $pluginsdir
File something.ext
; Do something with "$pluginsdir\something.ext"
; Note: $pluginsdir is automatically deleted when installer quits...
FunctionEnd
```